# Vagrant up gives error: Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Missing argument to '--name'

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I got a vagrant machine running ubuntu, which always worked. Today I got an error and I couldn't find a fix anywhere so far.

```
Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Missing argument to '--name'
```

I get this error when I try 'vagrant up'.

I tried adding a name in the vagrant file and in the puppet file used, but the error keeps showing up.

Any ideas?

Kind regards,

Nick

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: The property in the vagrant file shouldn't be "name:" but "id:".

Comment: I had the same problem and came across this answer. My Vagrant machine also always worked and it was one that I configured using PuPHPet, but upon upgrading vagrant to 1.6.5 I could not longer start the machine.

However what I found was the opposite of what you put here... I was able to fix it by changing 'id' to 'name' in my Vagrantfile.